# Filling content-length of x-accel-redirect?

Tags: django, nginx

How can I fill the `Content-Length` of an `X-Accel-Redirect` with django and nginx?

I'm currently using:

```
        response = HttpResponse()
        response['Content-Length'] = os.path.getsize(path)
        response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename="{}"'.format(os.path.basename(path))
        response['X-Accel-Redirect'] = server_file_path
```

But it is not working. When the user downloads a file the file's length doesn't appears!

Comment: Are you using gzip (check the `content-encoding` and `transfer-encoding` response headers)? If so, the transfer encoding may be chunked, so nginx will remove the `content-length` header

Comment: I'm just using those two that I posted, `Content-Length` and `Content-Disposition`

Comment: What is the status code when you use X-Accel-Redirect?

Comment: The status is 301, and I just saw that it says  transfer encoding: chunked!

Comment: I think that I'll be able to fix it with [Nginx removes Content-Length header for chunked content](http://serverfault.com/questions/482875/nginx-removes-content-length-header-for-chunked-content). Thanks so much for the help!